# how to add child without using scene as argument to make object a class variable

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have an init method in a Square class. I would like to make Square a class variable of the GameScene class, but currently I am passing the GameScene as an argument to add the child as a sprite. The init is below:

```
    init(squareType: SquareType, gameScene: GameScene) {
    self.squareType = SquareType
    sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: SquareType.simpleDescription())

    sprite.name = squareCategoryName
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(3*gameScene.frame.size.width/4, 3*gameScene.frame.size.height/4)

    sprite.zPosition = 4
    gameScene.addChild(sprite) // this is why I am using GameScene argument

    physicsProperties()

}
```

How can I rewrite my init so it can function in the same way without using the `GameScene` as an argument?

Comment: You can create squares (Square objects) inside GameScene and add them there. So, inside GameScene, just do addChild(squareObject).